# Kafka running on AWS - how to retain broker.id on new instance spun-up in-place of instance/broker failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

Kafka running on AWS - how to retain broker.id on new instance spun-up in-place of instance/broker failed.

We are currently running Kafka in AWS with broker.id gets auto generated. But we are having issues when a broker is failed, new broker/instance spun-up in AWS get assigned with new broker.id. The issue is, with this approach, we need to re-assign the topics/replications on to the new broker manually.

We learned that, replication can be auto resolved by Kafka, if we can manage to get the same broker.id on the new AWS instance spun-up in-place of failed broker/instance.

I have read, we can set broker.id.generation.enable= false, but what is the best way to identify and retain the broker.id? Any links/help is appreciated.

Comment: You could just assign `broker.id` to a number that you chose. When you move the volume off a failed instance,  set the same `broker.id` to that server (we also run in AWS and have generation to true, but have set up a value manually)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. so do you have any custom script which gets triggered during launch of instance to set-up the broker-id manually? something like script mentioned at some script mentioned @ tech.gc.com/scaling-with-kafka ? how do you get previous broker.id which is just failed without conflicting with other/existing broker ids?  We don't use EBS, instead we use instance level storage, so we loose storage/volume when AWS instance is terminated.

Comment: We use Terraform with a script written in-house, so there isn't any such auto-scaling things. It's all immutable and manually done, but it is using EBS. Our instances don't really drastically fail, though, but if they do, I guess the EBS volume migration is easily done.

Comment: Yeah, EBS is doing trick in your case.

Our case is specific: especially with instance level storage and not using EBS.

I am sure there should be easy/another way to retain the old broker.id for new AWS instance spun-up for auto replication.

Any other ideas/help is appreciated.

Comment: My only ideas involve configuration management tools like Ansible and not letting a Kafka service auto-start or pick its own id